# Java - How to use a variable from a method when imported into the main class

Tags: java, eclipse, class, variables, methods

I am trying to use a variable from a method I created in another class in the main section.

For example:

```
public class test {

public static int n;

public void getLower(){

    int p = 12;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    test example = new test();

    example.getLower();

    System.out.println(p);



}

}
```

However, I get the error message 'p cannot be resolved to a variable'.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: no its not possible. `p` is local to `getLower()`.

Comment: p is a local variable in an instance method. You can not access it in static main function. You can explain your problem, so that we could suggest the right solution.

Comment: Read tutorial on Java for beginners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p` is a *local* variable within the `getLower` method. You're not "importing" the method - you're just calling it. When the method has returned, the variable no longer even exists.

You could consider returning the value of `p` from the method:

```
public int getLower() {
    int p = 12;
    // Do whatever you want here
    return p;
}
```

Then assign the return value to a local variable in `main`:

```
int result = example.getLower();
System.out.println(result);
```

You should read the [Java tutorial on variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) for more information about the different kinds of variables.

Comment: This is perfect, just what I needed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

> Is what I'm trying to do possible?

No, unless you declare `p` the same way you are declaring `n`.

In your example, the `n` variable exists **only** in the `getLower()` method, it's not accessible by other methods, so you have to declare it at class-level:

```
public class test {

    public static int n;
    public static int p = 12;

    //.......
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

or

```
public class test {

    public static int n;
    public int p = 12;

    //.......
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test t = new test();
        System.out.println(t.p);
    }
}
```

[Read more about variable scope](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html)

Answer (score 0):

varaiable P is defined in the method getLower so it is local variable which cant be accessed in main method.You need to define the variable globally so that both the method can access it.So can make it static or simple variable

Answer (score 0):

p is a method variable, that means, it is garbage collected as soon as the method returns, so you can't get it, you can just return it's value and assign it to a local variable in the caller function